# Logic error in processing user input from a keypad

Tags: c, embedded

First of all this is homework.  I am trying to do the following:

The user should be be able to input one or two digit number solution with the proper sign.

I am programming a Freescale HCS12 micro controller.  So, I cannot use any of the C libraries.

I created the following function to grab user input from a keypad  one at a time.  Then, my goal is to print it to the LCD, and wait for the user to press the next key, if any.  If the user presses another number, then I concatenate it to the previous number.  I don't have to do error checking, so I can expect that the user will not input more than two numbers.

In the code, if the user presses 14, I return a negative number.

My problem is that for the number I finally save in the 'numberEntered' variable is not what the user pressed.

Below you will find my code:

```
 //this method will take user input and display it to LED
  int processAnswer(void)
  {
    int sign;  //if sign remains zero, then number entered by user is positive
    int counter;
    int negFlag;
    numberEntered = 0;
    sign = 0;  //if sign remains zero, then number entered by user is positive
    counter = 0;
    negFlag =0;
   //Program will continue to query for a key until someting is pressed
   //The number 0x1F is a number assigned in getKey() routine if no key is pressed
      inKey = 0;
      while(1){
        inKey = getkey();
        keyrelease(); //checks if key is released
        if(inKey == 15){
          break;
        }
        if(inKey == 0x1F){
          continue;
        }

        if(inKey != 14 && inKey != 0x1F ){
          counter++;

        }
        if(inKey != 14 && counter == 2 ){  
          numberEntered = numberEntered * 10;
          numberEntered = numberEntered + inKey;
          displayNumber(numberEntered);

        }

        if(inKey != 14 && numberEntered < 10){
          numberEntered = inKey;
          displayNumber(numberEntered);
        }
        if(inKey == 14 ){

          if(negFlag==0){

          Command(0x86);
          Print('-');
          sign = 1;
          negFlag = 1;
          }

          continue;
        }

      }//end of while loop


           //if user pressed key 'C', then delete input
        // if(inKey == 12) //if the user wants to delete latest input
        // {

        //  //Command(0x85); //sets cursor to address 0x05 of first line
        //  //Print(0x00);  //will clear previous input
        //  //Command(0x84);
        //  //Print(0x00);
        //  numberEntered=backspace(numberEntered);

        // }


  //return final answer from user
      if(sign == 1)
      {
        numberEntered = -numberEntered;
      }
      return numberEntered;
  }//end of processAnswer function
```

Comment: Are you asking why you are getting stuck or suggestions on how to reformat so you can process one number?  Because you can only process 2 keys because `displayNumber` is called in you 2nd loop after your 2nd called to `getkey`

Comment: I would like suggestions to process one number if only one number is pressed, and also handle two numbers.  So, my goal is that if the user presses one number followed by the key F, then i will return that single digit.  If the user enters two digits, then I return that number.  My code can't handle a one digit input correctly.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to structure into one loop, I'm sure there are bugs but you can work them out - something like:

```
sign = 0;
number = 0;
while (inKey == 0x0F) {
   inkey = getKey();
   keyRelease();

   if (inKey == 15)
      break;
   if (inKey == 14)
      sign = 1;
   else {
       number += inKey;
       displayNumber(number);
       number = number*10;
   }
 }
 if (sign && number) {
    number = ~number +1;
```

Comment: Thanks for your input.  I have changed my code since yesterday, but I still have bugs in it.  I will keep debugging  it.

Comment: There was no bugs in my final code of processAnswer(), it was elsewhere in my code.